# Eclipse Java Compiler Errors

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

What does the following error messages mean?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
Syntax error on token "]", :: expected after this token
Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeader
```

The line it does not like is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

My full WIP code in case you need to see it for context is as follows. Eclipse automatically sets in that line and I have never had issues with it before.

```
public class Card {

    public class cardValue()


    public static int suit;
    public static int faceValue;

    {
        static int getfaceValue()
            {
                return faceValue;
            }

        setfaceValue(String faceValue)
            {
                cardFaceValue = faceValue;
                return faceValue;
            }

         static int getSuit()
            {
                return suit;
            }

         setSuit(int suit)
            {
                cardSuit = suit;
                return suit;
            }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        cardValue card1 = new cardValue();




        // Suit values into strings for Hearts,Spades,Clubs, Diamonds
        if (cardValue.getSuit() == 1)

            {
            System.out.print(" of Hearts");
            }
        if  (cardValue.getSuit()  == 2)
            {
            System.out.print(" of Spades");
            }
        if  (cardValue.getSuit()  == 3)
            {
            System.out.print(" of Clubs");
            }
        if (cardValue.getSuit()  == 4)
            {
            System.out.print(" of Diamonds");
            }


        System.out.println(card1.getSuit());


    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Your **first** error is in line 3: `public class cardValue()`. What is that line even supposed to do?? See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/RVFXG2#cmperr). Fix your errors from the top (and there are a lot of them).

Comment: The error messages mean that your code is not valid Java and because of this Eclipse is unable to compile it. You can't run code that contains errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really recommend searching around and learning about classes and objects in Java.

But if I get what you're trying to do, this will just work:

```
public class Card {

    private int suit;
    private int faceValue;

    public Card (int suit, int faceValue) {
        setSuit(suit);
        setFaceValue(faceValue);
    }

    int getFaceValue () {
        return faceValue;
    }

    void setFaceValue (int faceValue) {
        this.faceValue = faceValue;
    }

    int getSuit () {
        return suit;
    }

    void setSuit (int suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Card card = new Card(1, 4);

        System.out.print(card.getFaceValue());
        // Suit values into strings for Hearts,Spades,Clubs, Diamonds
        if (card.getSuit() == 1) {
             System.out.println(" of Hearts");
        } else if (card.getSuit() == 2) {
            System.out.println(" of Spades");
        } else if (card.getSuit() == 3) {
            System.out.println(" of Clubs");
        } else if (card.getSuit() == 4) {
            System.out.println(" of Diamonds");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

IF you have imports inside class declaration, need to come before your class declaration.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
```

or similar

Check your indentation, which is incorrect. You may have {} out of balance.

```
class Card {

private int suit;
private int faceValue;

public Card (int suit, int faceValue)
{
    setSuit(suit);
    setfaceValue(faceValue);
}

int getfaceValue () {
    return faceValue;
}

void setfaceValue (int faceValue) {
    this.faceValue = faceValue;
}

int getSuit () {
    return suit;
}

void setSuit (int suit) {
    this.suit = suit;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Card card = new Card(1, 4);

    System.out.print(card.getfaceValue());
    // Suit values into strings for Hearts,Spades,Clubs, Diamonds
    if (card.getSuit() == 1) {
         System.out.println(" of Hearts");
    } else if (card.getSuit()  == 2) {
        System.out.println(" of Spades");
    } else if (card.getSuit()  == 3) {
        System.out.println(" of Clubs");
    } else if (card.getSuit()  == 4) {
        System.out.println(" of Diamonds");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What `import` statements?

Comment: *"Also you should write backwards, which can improve your indentation."* What?

Comment: You mean the only difference that you fixed his `getfaceValue` method call? Or do you mean the coincidence of using the exact same inconsistent brace style, the exact same arguments for the `Card` constructor and the exact same (and unusual) whitespace before method parenthese?

Comment: @Tom Probably he/she did some edit on his/her old code.. currently,there is one more issue with his/her code.. but with this edited code.. you can't find any error.

Comment: It's only my 4th programl. I'm trying to understand the error messages that my compiler gives me. I understand the code isn't perfect but I am still learning. Part of that process is to figure out what the compiler is trying to tell me. Thank you everyone for your input, I was able to learn a bit more about what was going on.